# GIT - Files being overwritten

Tags: git

I am using Git now for a short time, and I have experienced a few annoying things. I have a few branches now, however, when I switch branches, my config files are being overwritten (they are in my .gitignore). How is this possible, and what things can I do to find out what causes this issue?

Comment: `.gitignore` is for ignoring *untracked* files.

Answer (score 2):

make sure, that config-files are not present in git repositories. `.gitignore` merely prevents changes from being committed, but doesn't ignore files which are already committed.

So, `git rm yourconfig.file` in every branch, put local copies in directories and it will work just fine

Comment: And how can I do that in other branches without checking out and overwriting my files?

Comment: Besides, this is just a workaround. I would love to see `.gitignore` work.

Comment: `.gitignore` DOES work. it just doesn't do what you expect it to do. regarding first comment: copy your configs to a separate place, do `git rm` and manually restore the files after you did it in every branch

Comment: How does it work when it doesn't ignore the files listed in there?

Comment: @ArkoElsenaar you can't claim that `.gitignore` doesn't work if you don't understand **how** it works.